# Not getting full branch name on mac(m1) terminal

Tags: git, awk, zsh

Code:

```
# Find and set branch name var if in git repository.
function git_branch_name()
{
  branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}')
  if [[ $branch == "" ]];
  then
    :
  else
    echo '-%F{#ff00f7}('$branch')%f'
  fi
}

# Enable substitution in the prompt.
setopt prompt_subst

# Config for prompt. PS1 synonym.
prompt='%F{#1dc223}%n%f@%F{#00ffd0}%1~%f$(git_branch_name)$ '
```

This is the code I have on .zshrc file, and "git_branch_name" is the function to get the branch name on my terminal.

It is working fine for all branches but when I have a branch that name including forward slash (/), it's giving me last chunk only.

Example:
branch name: main -> main
branch name: feat/process -> process

But I need the full branch name "feat/process".

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: @Shiva : You output `$branch` within single quotes. They inhibit parameter expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Linux, macOS, or Terminal, and very little to do with Git: it's because you told `awk` to print just the last slash-separated component:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}'
```

If you don't want just the last slash-separated component, don't ask for that.  There's no need to use `awk` here at all: use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to produce the abbreviated name of the current branch, if there is a current branch, or `HEAD` if not; or use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` to produce the abbreviated name of the current branch, or an error if there is no current branch.

Comment: When I use "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" or "git symbolic-ref --short HEAD",
I'm getting this error on the terminal open.
"fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Can we avoid this?

Comment: Only run the command when in a Git repository. Or, discard the error *output* (as your existing code does), and detect or ignore the error *exit* as appropriate. Note that `2>/dev/null` means *send the error output to the discard device*.